# Creating a simple class with a couple of methods - one of which doesn't work

Tags: class

class Burger:
burger_left = 100
buy = False

```
def buy(self):
  self.buy = True
  print("What a good idea!")

def eat(self, delta):
  if self.buy:
    self.burger_left = self.burger_left - delta
  print("Yummy!")
  else:
    print("You need to buy the burger first")
```

#I was expecting the code to print "You need to buy the burger first" when fed a burger which had not been previously bought, but this does not work.

Comment: Spacing matters in python: your `print("Yummy!")` is executed outside of the `if` block, and the `else:` doesn't make sense as it is written. Having `Burger.buy` as a static class variable doesn't make much sense either: if you buy one burger, you've bought them all.